# Código PHP dentro de JQuery, é possível?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma aplicação e nela uso JQuery e a função que estou com problemas é o seguinte:

Quando o usuário clica no botão `+` chama o JQuery que lê um conteúdo HTML e PHP e executa numa linha abaixo para inserir um novo registro, porém com o PHP não quer funcionar. Como faço?

```js
(function($) {

  RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');

    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
      tr.remove();
    });

    return false;
  };

  var counter = 1;
  jQuery('a.add').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery(
      '<tr>' +
      '<td style="width: 300px">' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<select name="Produto" id="produto" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">' +
      <?php
          $sql = "SELECT id_Produto, cod_Produto, dsc_Produto from produtos ORDER BY cod_Produto ASC";
          $resultado = mysql_query($sql);

          while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
              $id_Produto = $linha['id_Produto'];
              $cod_Produto = $linha['cod_Produto'];
              $dsc_Produto = $linha['dsc_Produto'];
                                                    
              echo"<option value='$id_Produto'> $cod_Produto  |  $dsc_Produto   </option>";
          }
      ?>
      '</select>' +
      '</div> ' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td id="un"></td>' +
      '<td id="vol"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="volume" id="volume" style="width: 50px; margin: 0;"></td>' +
      '<td id="qtd"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantidade" id="quantidade" style="width: 60px; margin: 0"></td>' +
      '<td id="peso"></td>' +
      '<td id="uni"></td>' +
      '<td id="tot"></td>' +
      '<td id="desc"></td>' +
      '<td id="liq"></td>' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
    jQuery('table.table-bordered').append(newRow);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sim é possível mas não vai funcionar da maneira que você espera. Lembre que o php executa no lado servidor (apenas uma vez por requisição) e o javascript no lado cliente. O mais recomendado é utilizar um ajax para montar esses combos caso tenham valores diferentes se forem iguais pode clonar o elemento.

Comment: Como assim? De qual forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando um arquivo `.js` ou seja, só javascript pode ser executado aí dentro, se você quiser executar PHP e javascript, teria de fazer algo do tipo:

```
//arquivo script.php

<script>
    ...código jquery/javascript
</script>

<?php
foreach ($usuarios as $bla) {
    echo $bla;
} //só um exemplo
?>
```

Mas aqui o PHP iria executar primeiro e não poderia executar novamente.
Solução: Use Requisições AJAX. Cada vez que o usuário clicar neste botão, envie uma requisição ajax para um arquivo separado, assim a cada requisição o PHP será executado separadamente e retornará o HTML desejado.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Veja alguns tutorias na internet (youtube) tem este site da w3schools, que muita gente fala que está antigo, mas é bom pra quem ta começando: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp um melhor seria o site da mozilla , O MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/